# Sending emails only to half of data extension list

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

There are data extensions. I am sending emails by selecting the whole list. But email is being sent to only half or less than half in the list. What could be possible reasons?

Comment: One possibility I've seen a lot of clients run into (but I doubt it accounts for 50% of a list) is the default behavior of list detective to exclude non-personal addresses such as:

info@something.com
sales@something.com 
etc.

Support can help to set a "custom allow" rule for list detective.

Comment: Have you checked if the subscribers are opt-ed in or if they have a status of 'Unsubscribed'?

Answer (score 0):

It is to little information and a description that is not precise. I encourage you to rephrase your question and give as much information as you can do without showing customer data. Especially the description with dataextensions and lists is quite bad formulated. Lists and dataextensions are two completely different things.

1. Contacts that have an unsubscribe status inside that list and you try to send with a commercial sender profile could be one.
2. Duplicate email addresses all over the place with the option "deduplicate subscribers" inside the normal send process (all duplicate email addresses get pushed out).
3. Contacts that are inside the suppression period / pending deletions.
4. Exclusions scripts that you might have set.
5. Throttling processes that have been missconfigured and a dataextension that gets overwritten meanwhile that process.
6. A different user that stops the sending process when its scheduled and not finished (still processing the sends).
7. ...

Comment: Although you list valid possibilities, I am not sure this is an answer. This would serve better as a comment. As the information is valid, I don't think it deserves to be flagged or deleted - but I would look to put a simplified version of this inside a comment for the future.

Comment: Hi Gortonington, at first i was creating a comment for it but then i realized that this comment would be to long. So i came up with the idea to just do it as an answer rather than writing two comments that do not offer a good overview because you cannot create numbered lists in there. But you are right this is a mixed answer - comment stuff.

Comment: Sometimes it is best to save the possibilities for a solution until you get further clarification on the issue. 'Over Solving' can cause confusion more often than clarity.